# How to receive an JSON string from a socket

Tags: c#, json, string, sockets

I want to send JSON strings back and forth over a socket connection in c# (xamarin).

I want to know, how does the receiver know how many bytes to read from the socket in order to receive the complete JSON string because the string will vary in size.

Do I have to send a length first in binary (maybe one or two bytes), then the JSON string? What is the standard way to do it so that the receiver knows how many bytes to read from the socket each time it get a complete JSON string.

It has to know how many bytes per string because each string is a separate packet, and if many packets are send back to back, if the length of each string is not known exactly, it will read past the end of one string and into the beginning of another, or not read the whole string, either way it will crash while decoding the malformed string.

Another problem, if I send the length first in binary, then if anything should happen where the receiver gets out of sync with the sender, then it wont know which byte is the length anymore because it cant tell where the strings start, and which incoming data represents the length, it will just receive a bunch of bytes and it wont know where is the start from where is the end etc.

Anybody knows the proper way to do it without writing a megabyte of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string based message(as you mentioned JSON), you can use a `StringBuilder` to **concat** each packet you received, and check at every receive step for an **End of File** tag(which is defined by yourself, e.g. `<EOF>`).

Here is an example on MSDN

[Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) implementations: Client sends messages ending with `<EOF>` tag and server checks for it to make sure each message is completed.